# How can I save/download for offline reading?

Tags: windows-10

Looking for ways to get this offline. I am a paying subscriber! Just want to be  able to save and read offline.

http://echoesmagazine.co.uk/magazine/Echoes-December2016/

Comment: They posted the password earlier.

Comment: Does the page have a printing option? Windows 10 has a built in PDF printer. So print to PDF, read offline.

Comment: I have the password and am a paying subscriber. Just want to know if it is possible to read offline and save the information.

Comment: Cool! That works. Question answered!!!

Comment: Posted a proper answer - the *preview* link on the main page would have done fine as an example. You could probably reflect that in your question. Also, in future, *please* don't stick usernames and passwords for subscriptions and such on the public internet.

Answer (score 2):

From the *[preview](http://echoesmagazine.co.uk/preview/Echoes-Magazine-Preview.pdf.html)* page, which isn't password protected

[image]

Click on the printer icon - select print range all and ok. Assuming you have Windows 10, pick Microsoft Print to PDF - else install some other PDF printer like [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/).

Save it as a PDF and you're all good.

Comment: Excellent! It works. Question answered. Thanks